# FFMPEG How to insert short video and audio in longer video in specific time, size and position

Tags: video, time, ffmpeg, size, duration

FFMPEG How to insert short video (4sec) in longer video in specific time (from 15th to 19th second) and specific size. Long video is 1920x1080px and inserted video should be 1720x820px, positioned in the middle?

file info..
Duration: 00:00:22.07, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3982 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 3900 kb/s, 29 fps, 29 tbr, 14848 tbn, 58 tbc (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'short.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : mp42
minor_version   : 19529854
compatible_brands: mp42isom
creation_time   : 2020-10-25T11:01:10.000000Z
Duration: 00:00:03.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 14405 kb/s
Stream #1:0(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 319 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
creation_time   : 2020-10-25T11:01:10.000000Z
handler_name    : Sound Media Handler
Stream #1:1(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 14078 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 119.88 tbc (default)
Metadata:
creation_time   : 2020-10-25T11:01:10.000000Z
handler_name    : Video Media Handler
encoder         : AVC Coding

Comment: There's numerous video-editing tools you can explore, including open source tools on many different platforms. If you are used to conmmand-line tools I suggest looking at ffmpeg tools suite and documentation.

Comment: @Milos this is a **programming** forum. Are you using a programming language to edit the video or you just want some recommendation for an existing utility app to use? If not a coding problem then maybe use your same account to ask at [**video** production](https://video.stackexchange.com/). On this forum you cannot ask for software recommends (breaks anti-advertising rules)... Anyways a free tool is FFmpeg (Win/Mac/Linux) but you have to type the commands. Download  and test it.

Comment: I totally missed to write it is FFMPEG...  I tried some codes that I found on net but either they have some problems or they do not have all variables that I need.

Comment: Do you want the short video to be overlaid over long video, and the two audios mixed together? Or do you want a concatenation, where long video is interrupted by short video then long video continues? Either way we need info about your inputs. This can be provided by running `ffmpeg -i long.mp4 -i short.mp4` and copying then pasting the complete text output.

Comment: I need short video overlaid over long one.  During that time should be audio from short video.

Comment: llogan, I added file info in original post..